# How do bull’s eye squalls occur?

Tags: atmosphere, wind, clouds

The only things I could find on the internet were that they had vortices and are marked by an isolated cloud, for example, in the American Met. Soc. glossary: https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Bull%27s_eye_squall.

How do bulls eye squalls occur?

Comment: What is a bull's eye squall?  Not a term I'm familiar with

Comment: a bulls eye squall is a weather  phenomenon.

Comment: Not one I've heard before (as a meteorologist).  So think it would help to give us more background (location you live, where you hear it, what the term means)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest its a very very bad known phenomen. I heard in university about it however just as a side note (it was observed roughly 10 times). Squals are more popular I guess...

Comment: @jeopardy tempest https://ggweather.com/winds.html

Answer (score 0):

This weather phenomenon occurs when, due to ascending winds above a typically invisible storm or vortex, there is a significant acceleration (for at least 1 minute). Hence the term "squall," which describes the increase in wind speed.
However during storms, Bulls Eye is the term used when it causes significant damage to property (similar to hitting the bull's eye in archery). Besides these fast winds, there are also Bulls Eye storms, etc.

This phenomenon often occurs in countries where high air temperatures can be generated, such as Argentina, Chile, etc.

Comment: Quit those ai generated responses

Comment: Nope sry or ask your ai and See what See answeres If you want to Unserstand the way i searced i Just Split the therm and Afterwards Look If my explanation make sence with observed phenomenons.

Comment: Bulls eye squalls, also known as "eye-like" squalls, are a meteorological phenomenon characterized by the formation of a circular or ring-shaped band of intense precipitation surrounding a clear or relatively calm area, similar to the eye of a hurricane. These squalls are often associated with convective systems, such as thunderstorms or mesoscale convective complexes.

Comment: Thats the answer from ChatGPT and here you can see how AI missinterpretates the Therm Bulles eye. The only thing AI on my answer is the gramma correction (as you see my english isn´t the best)

Comment: And pls Tell me or US why you think this answer is AI generated...